# Selecting Nth Record in an SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an SQL Query that i'm running but I only want to select a specific row. For example lets say my query was:

```
Select * from Comments
```

Lets say this returns 10 rows, I only want to select the 8th record returned by this query. I know I can do:

```
Select Top 5 * from Comments
```

To get the top 5 records of that query but I only want to select a certain record, is there anything I can put into this query to do that (similar to top).

Thanks

jack

Comment: What database platform are you using? Sql2000? Sql2005? Oracle?

Comment: I'd have to ask "why the 8th"? Is there something special about the 8th that might make it easier to select using a regular where clause?

Comment: No nothing special about the 8th, it's just what popped into my head. I'm using SQL2005

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a classic interview question.

In Ms SQL 2005+ you can use the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) keyword and have the Predicate ROW_NUMBER = n

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
)  

SELECT * 
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber = 5;
```

In SQL2000 you could do something like

```
SELECT Top 1 *FROM
[tblApplications]
where [ApplicationID] In
(
    SELECT TOP 5 [ApplicationID]
    FROM [dbo].[tblApplications]
    order by applicationId Desc
)
```

Comment: Would you say that this is the correct way of doing things? (If there is such a thing) I'm seeing 3 different methods of achiving what I'm, after on this page but am wondering if any of the three offer any particular advantages (efficiency etc)

Comment: As others have said. Why do you need the 8th specifically? To ask for nth where there is some other predicate is often the preferable option. If you are getting the nth once every so often does it need to be optimised for performance.

Comment: The best way to guage "best" in this sort of instance is to test the techniques against a test dataset that closely matches the balance of your live dataset (but is preferably larger if your live dataset is small at the moment) and see what the query planner does in response to them. Look at the apparently query plan, to see if anything nasty like full table scans are starting to turn up where they are not in other methods, and also watch the results coming out of the SQL profiler to see if the techniques differ greatly in the CPU or page read load for other reasons.

Comment: @John, that SQL2K query does not do what you think it does.

Comment: oops yeah now fixed but untested. I just grabbed a query I had written and altered it without evenb looking at the results, In my defence, I was full of wine :O)

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
   (SELECT TOP 8 * FROM Comments ORDER BY foo ASC)
ORDER BY foo DESC
```

Comment: works for SQL2K. note that if foo isn't unique, which row gets returned is non-determinate.

Comment: This is very inefficient because of the two selects.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should say which RDBMS you're using.

Second, you should give careful thought to what it is you're trying to accomplish. Relational Databases are set-based. In general, the order of elements in a set does not matter. You'll want to ask why it matters in this case, then see if there's a better way to embed the concept of order into the query itself.

For instance, in SQL Server 2005 (and other RDBMS), you can use the ROW_NUMBER function to assign a sequential number to each row returned, based on the criteria you specify. You could then select rows based on the row number. Example from Books Online:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

Comment: John: will adding a TOP clause in the inner query change the performance? i.e. SELECT TOP N SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
where N = the max limit of row number (60 in this case)

What do you think?

Comment: I guess the comments above make sense when the N is in the lower range of number of records being selected. e.g. if I want records between 50 to 60 from 10000 records.

Comment: I think you should try it and find out, looking at the execution plan. SQL Server is capable of noticing that the outer SELECT includes a test on the value of the ROW_NUMBER function in the CTE. It's quite possible that it will not just select all SalesOrderHeader rows and only then filter. You should try it and find out.

Comment: I don't have SQL Server installed on my machine. So, I can't try it out. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ...conditions... LIMIT 1 OFFSET 8
```

OFFSET is a good thing for MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Well, in T-SQL (the dialect for SQL Server) you can do the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM (SELECT TOP 8 *
          FROM Table
         ORDER
            BY SortField)
 ORDER
    BY SortField DESC
```

This way you get the 8th record.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005:

```
select rank() OVER (ORDER BY c.subject, c.date) as rank, c.subject, c.date
   from comments c
   where rank = 8
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error on rank:

Invalid column name 'rank'.

If I execute everything up until the where I'm getting a table that looks as I think it should including a column called rank, bit odd that I can't use the where along with the rest of the statement

Comment: This won't work - you can't reference the rank column unless you place it in a derived table or a CTE - like this:

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY c.subject, c.date) AS rank, c.subject, c.date
FROM comments c) AS a
WHERE a.rank = 8

Answer (score 1):

I have read the question & your comments on you would want next 3 blog comments etc.

How is your tables structured?
Assume that you have blog post Id & comment Id is generated in ascending order for each blog post, you could do a SELECT based on the current Id.

e.g. if the blogpostId = 101, you get the top 3 comments order by posted Id. Now lets say, you want to get the next 3 comments - you could do a SELECT WHERE commentId between the last comment id shown TO the comment id - 3

But all that depends on how your tables are defined.

Comment: definitely. make the front end do more bookkeeping.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL 2000 where you do not have ROW_NUMBER() function you could use a work-around like this:

```
SELECT CommentsTableFieldList, IDENTITY(INT, 1,1) as seqNo 
INTO #SeqComments 
FROM Comments

SELECT * FROM #SeqComments 
WHERE seqNo = 8
```

Comment: that's not the way to create temp tables. use the #-prefix, unless you need to create an ordinary user table that happens to live in tempdb.

Comment: Clumsy. Use this: SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM (SELECT TOP 8 ... ORDER BY x ASC) foo ORDER BY x DESC

Comment: Not always you have a column to perform the sorting and its reverse.

Comment: this is better: with NO ORDER applied

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 *
from TableName
where ColumnName1 in
(
    select top nth ColumnName1
    from TableName
    order by ColumnName1 desc
)
order by ColumnName1 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [SELECT reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html), use the LIMIT keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
```

*Note: this is for MySQL, other SQL engines may have a different keyword.*

Answer (score 0):

```
Select from tablename limit nthrow,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try This

Let us assume , We want select 5th row of WC_Video Table
And

```
Select * from (Select Row_Number() over (Order by Uploadedon) as 'rownumber',* from Wc_Video )as Temp where rownumber=5
```