# SQL query by record number

Tags: sql, oracle

Referring to this question, no solution/answer was given for Oracle platform.
[Selecting Nth Record in an SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022514/selecting-nth-record-in-an-sql-query)

No sort or group or where clause. Order as per inserted record.

Reason for this, my application log stated that record no 7,34,46 are throwing error. Is there any correct way to archive this?

Thx in advance.

Comment: "Order as per inserted record." You are going to sort by some column. Insertion order is not maintained.

Comment: There is no such thing as "*order as per inserted record*". The phyiscal location of rows might change over time. You can only determine the order in which rows are inserted by storing the insertion time in a timestamp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the accepted answer from that link is (almost) perfectly valid for Oracle:

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS "RowNumber"
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
)  
SELECT * 
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE "RowNumber" = 5;
```

Oracle has an analytic function ROW_NUMBER() that follows this syntax.  I changed the single quotes to double quotes for the column alias, but I think everything else is good.

UPDATE:

As far as retrieving Nth record based on insertion time, you cannot rely on Oracle to maintain the insertion order for you.  If you do not specify a sort order, there's no guarantee what order your results are going to come back in.  If you have a primary key that is always populated by a sequence, that could be used to order by.  Alternatively, you could populate a timestamp column upon insertion and use that to order by.  Long story short, you can't have a meaningful Nth record query without specifying a sort order.

Comment: Can we use this without ordering?

Comment: @DanA.: Your comment should be part of your answer. Since OP wants order by insertion time, I think the answer should address how (and if) that is possible.

Comment: @ZaimanNoris: no. You can **not** determine the "nth" row without ordering.