# TSQL Translate ChangeData Field in CRM 2011

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, crm, csv

I have a delimited string which acts as a key for a target delimited string. I need to know where 2 values are in the key sequence, and then pull only those positions from my target string.

Example 1
Key : ,15,90,104,73,95,13,14,
Target : Medium~Male~28~Green~Right~No~10/04/2013

Example 2
Key : ,14,73,104,95,15,13,90,
Target : 12/03/2013~Green~28~Right~Medium~No~Male~

I only care about the gender and date values in the target and the corresponding entries in the key will always be 14 and 90

Once I know where those values are sequentially (positions 2 & 7 in example 1), I need to pull out the same sections of my target string so I end up with the gender and the date values in their own variables

I have changed the type of data I'm looking for to make the question easier to understand

I hope that made sense

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , k NVARCHAR(100)
    , t NVARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (k, t)
VALUES 
    (',15,90,104,73,95,13,14,', 'Medium~Male~28~Green~Right~No~10/04/2013'),
    (',14,73,104,95,15,13,90,', '12/03/2013~Green~28~Right~Medium~No~Male~')

SELECT 
      data.id
    , data.p
    , data.r 
FROM (
    SELECT 
          p = p.value('(.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
        , po = p.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i])', 'int')
        , r = r.value('(.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
        , ro = r.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i])', 'int')
        , d.id
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              t.id
            , txml = CAST('<r><s>' + REPLACE(t.k + ',', ',', '</s>' + '<s>') + '</s></r>' AS XML)
            , kxml = CAST('<r><s>' + REPLACE(t.t + '~', '~', '</s>' + '<s>') + '</s></r>' AS XML)  
        FROM @temp t
    ) d
    CROSS APPLY kxml.nodes('/r/s') t(p)
    CROSS APPLY txml.nodes('/r/s') k(r)
) data
WHERE data.po = data.ro - 1
    AND data.r IN ('14', '90')
    --AND r + data.p != ''
ORDER BY data.id
```

Comment: Fantastic!!

Thank you both very much for your help on this.

Comment: I didn't mean to un-accept this solution. I thought I could accept 2 simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

You can split the two strings (see here: [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)).

Then, when you have splitted the strings in two table objects, access at the N-th record (e.g. using the TOP keyword) in both and you can get the result.

Given the two strings and an int you can write a function to get the two coupled values.

Comment: The only problem with that solution is each time a target and key are generated the length can vary drastically so there is no way to know the number of columns I need.
I was hoping that it would be possible to store the sequential value of in a variable and then use that variable to extract the relevant section from the target

Comment: If I can understand well your comment and reading again your question, I think once you have splitted your values in a table (variable, temporary or physical it doesn't matter) as the function does, you can get the nth record of that table. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022514/selecting-nth-record-in-an-sql-query

Comment: But regardless of the type of table I use won't I have to define a number of columns? I won't know how many columns I need because the amount of values in my string will alter

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to your use of the word 'columns'. With that kind of function, your strings ar splitted in rows, not columns, so you should not have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick Follow up, I had trouble applying the above solution (probably due to a lack of knowledge on my part) so I created the following functions and they do the job

GET SEQUENTIAL VALUE ----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
DECLARE @Attributemask varchar(max) = '[PASS IN KEY STRING]' 
DECLARE @Required varchar(10) = '[PASS IN VALUE TO LOOK FOR FOLLOWED BY A COMMA]'
DECLARE @AttPosition int
DECLARE @TempString varchar(max)
DECLARE @Result as int

SET @AttPosition = CHARINDEX(@Required, @Attributemask)
SET @TempString = LEFT(@Attributemask, @AttPosition)
SET @Result = len(@TempString)-len(replace(@TempString,',',''))
SELECT @Result
```

GET DATA ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
DECLARE @ChangeData varchar(max) = '[PASS IN TARGET STRING]'
DECLARE @AttPos int = [PASS IN RESULT FROM PREVIOUS FUNCTION] 
DECLARE @Count int = 1
DECLARE @NotNeeded varchar(100)
Declare @Result varchar(max)

SET @ChangeData = '~'+@ChangeData

WHILE @Count < (@AttPos +1)
BEGIN
    SET @NotNeeded = CHARINDEX('~', @ChangeData)
    SET @ChangeData = right(@ChangeData,len(@ChangeData) - @NotNeeded)
    IF len(@ChangeData) = 0 BREAK
    SET @Count = @Count +1
END

SET @Result = LEFT(@ChangeData, (CHARINDEX('~', @ChangeData)))
SET @Result = LEFT(@Result, (LEN(@Result)-1))
Select @Result
```