# How to SELECT only the "nth" record from a query result?

Tags: t-sql

I have a T-SQL query that return X records ordered.

I want to get only on record  , for instance, only the 5th record from that result: how ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting Nth Record in an SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022514/selecting-nth-record-in-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to update your query.

I.e in oracle we have rownum that assign rownumber to every row.

You can do like this,

```
Select * from(
Select a.*, rownum as n from your table) where n = 3;
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH NumberedTable AS
    (
        SELECT 
                RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <'Order Column here'>)
            ,   *
        FROM    <'Table Name here'>
    )
    
SELECT  *
FROM NumberedTable
WHERE RowNo = <'Record No. here'>
```